# How to write $a/(c+1)$ as $(a/c) + \cdots$?

Tags: fractions

I am looking for a way to rewrite

$$ \frac{a}{c+1} $$ as

$$ \frac{a}{c} + \cdots $$

in other words, move the $+ 1$ part outside of the denominator.

*(a and c are real numbers)*

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: This is going to be a smartaleck answer but $\frac{a}{c+1}=\frac{a}{c}+(\frac{a}{c+1}-\frac{a}{c})$.  Now... if you insist on continuing, then try simplifying $\frac{a}{c+1}-\frac{a}{c}$.  The end result is that it will not be worth having done and does not simplify matters at all.

Comment: Whether it "simplifies matters at all" depends on your needs. I *have* done calculations where the exact manipulation you propose *is* a useful simplification for what I'm doing.

Comment: My main point being, this isn't going to be the same as how $\frac{a+1}{c} = \frac{a}{c}+\frac{1}{c}$... I have seen several people who are not well practiced in math try to make the simplification that $\frac{a}{c+1}=\frac{a}{c}+\frac{a}{1}$ which is incorrect.  Performing the simplification I pointed out earlier yields you with $\frac{a}{c+1}=\frac{a}{c}-\frac{a}{c^2+c}$ which would appear to be more trouble to calculate by hand than it would have originally been since $\frac{a}{c^2+c}$ is just $\frac{a}{c+1}$ divided by $c$ an additional time.

Comment: One possibility is the series expansion $\frac{a}{c+1} = \frac{a}{c} - \frac{a}{c^2} + \frac{a}{c^3} - \frac{a}{c^4} + \cdots$ valid if $|c| < 1$.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $|c| > 1$?

Answer (score 1):

For something slightly different, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{a}{1 + c} &= \frac{a}{c} \left( \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{c}}\right) = \frac{a}{c} \left( \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{c^n} \right) 
\\&= \frac{a}{c}\left(1 - \frac{1}{c} + \frac{1}{c^2} + \cdots \right) = \frac{a}{c} - \frac{a}{c^2} + \frac{a}{c^3} + \cdots
\end{align}
This series will converge as long as $|c| > 1$.

Answer (score 0):

We go a bit farther and show that $\tfrac{a}{c+1}$ and $\tfrac{a}{c}$ are algebraically independent whenever $a$ and $c$ are.

Assume $a$ and $c$ are algebraically independent: that is, for all polynomials $f$ with integer coefficients,
$$f(a,c)=0\Rightarrow f = 0\text{.}$$ Suppose we had a polynomial relation
$$p(\tfrac{a}{c+1},\tfrac{a}{c})=0$$
between $\tfrac{a}{c+1}$ and $\tfrac{a}{c}$. Then since
$$p(\tfrac{a}{c+1},\tfrac{a}{c})=(c+1)^{-i}c^{-j}q(a,c)$$
for some natural numbers $i$, $j$ and polynomial $q$, we would have a relation
$$q(a,c)=0\text{,}$$
implying that $q=0$. Therefore $p=0$ as well, i.e.,
$$p(\tfrac{a}{c+1},\tfrac{a}{c})=0\Rightarrow p =0\text{.}$$
QED